# Cannot find symbol method addMouseListeners() in acm.program.GraphicsProgram

Tags: java, mouselistener, acm-java-libraries

I've been working through *The Art & Science of Java* text and SEE CS106A course. Everything has been going smoothly until interactive graphics programs were introduced. The following code, taken directly from the text, will not compile:

```
/*
 * File: DrawLines.java
 * -----------------------
 * This program allows a user to draw lines to the canvas.
 */

import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class DrawLines extends GraphicsProgram {

    public void run() {
        addMouseListeners();
    }

    /** Called on mouse press to record the coordinates of the click */
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        double x = e.getX();
        double y = e.getY();
        line = new GLine(x, y, x, y);
        add(line);
    }

    /** Called on mouse drag to reposition the object */
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        double x = e.getX();
        double y = e.getY();
        line.setEndPoint(x, y);
    }

    private GLine line;

}
```

It fails on line 14 with a `cannot find symbol: method addMouseListeners()` error. ACM ConsolePrograms and GraphicsPrograms without that method call work fine. As far as I can tell this method [should be valid](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/javadoc/student/index.html).

Am I doing something wrong here? Are the ACM documentation and textbook outdated? How do I add a mouse listener here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `karel.jar`, a library used in the first assignment of CS106A, interferes with the `addMouseListeners()` method. Removing `karel.jar` from source resolves the issue.